# filter JSON object based on specific value present inside nested object

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, filter, reduce

Hi I am trying to filter my JSON response to only get those values which are >=0.

> My response is below :

```
  {
    "response": [{
            "countryId": {
                "id": "10050020025",
                "idScheme": "externalId"
            },
            "processedDateTime": "2019-11-07 05:39:09",
            "AAE": [{
                "amount": "1000",
                "currencyCode": "USD"
            }],
            "TAE": [{
                "amount": "0",
                "currencyCode": "USD"
            }]
        },
        {
            "countryId": {
                "id": "10291520071",
                "idScheme": "InternalId"
            },
            "processedDateTime": "2019-02-03 08:21:22",
            "AAE": [{
                "amount": "0",
                "currencyCode": "USD"
            }],
            "TAE": [{
                "amount": "-2001",
                "currencyCode": "USD"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

> I am trying to achieve :

```
{
"response": [{
        "countryId": {
            "id": "10050020025",
            "idScheme": "externalId"
        },
        "processedDateTime": "2019-11-07 05:39:09",
        "AAE": [{
            "amount": "1000",
            "currencyCode": "USD"
        }]
    },
    {
        "countryId": {
            "id": "10291520071",
            "idScheme": "InternalId"
            },
            "processedDateTime": "2019-02-03 08:21:22",
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to use map & filter from es6 to achieve this but not good with don't know how i can do that.
so far i am trying some hardcoded approach as.

```
const outputResponse = response
.map(value => value)
.filter(value => value.AAE[0].amount !== '0')
```

but it will remove whole object which don't have amount '0'.

Any help be appreciated.

Comment: `.map(value => value)` what's the purpose of writing this? it's like doing `a=a`.

Comment: i am learning es6 not know how to do it properly.

Comment: Ok, in that case you won't need to use `filter` using `.map()` is enough, but you should transform the mapped objects correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just need an **[`Array#map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** call to map all the `response` objects and remove the `AAE` and `TAE` or targeted `keys` values which has `amount` < 0:

```
let keys = ["AAE", "TAE"];

let result = data.response.map(val => {
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (val[key] && val[key].some(x => +x.amount <= 0)) {
      delete val[key];
    }
  });
  return val;
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
let keys = ["AAE", "TAE"];

let data = {
  "response": [{
      "countryId": {
        "id": "10050020025",
        "idScheme": "externalId"
      },
      "processedDateTime": "2019-11-07 05:39:09",
      "AAE": [{
        "amount": "1000",
        "currencyCode": "USD"
      }],
      "TAE": [{
        "amount": "0",
        "currencyCode": "USD"
      }]
    },
    {
      "countryId": {
        "id": "10291520071",
        "idScheme": "InternalId"
      },
      "processedDateTime": "2019-02-03 08:21:22",
      "AAE": [{
        "amount": "0",
        "currencyCode": "USD"
      }],
      "TAE": [{
        "amount": "-2001",
        "currencyCode": "USD"
      }]
    }
  ]
};

let result = data.response.map(val => {
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (val[key] && val[key].some(x => +x.amount <= 0)) {
      delete val[key];
    }
  });
  return val;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I have 20-30 keys as "AAE" & "TAE" how can i achieve without if condition writing each time.

Comment: @VirendersinghRathore You can put all these keys in an array and iterate over it to that, see my Edit.

Comment: thnx that was really helpful.